# Python line ending ' '

Tags: python

This code

```
with open('iter.txt') as f:
    try:
        while True:
            line = next(f)
            print(line,end='')
    except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Works as expected.
But with

```
    print(line,end='\n')
```

Empty line is inserted.

```
Iteration is one of Python’s strongest features. At a high level, you might simply view

iteration as a way to process items in a sequence. However, there is so much more that

is possible, such as creating your own iterator objects,
```

Why?
Is there any alternative with os.linesep?

Comment: the text file probably already ends every line with a `\n`, you're doubling it.

Comment: How to check if it ends with \n?

Comment: Do you want your last line to be with `end=''` ?

Comment: `\n` is the *definition* of a line. If you're reading lines from the file, they definitely end with that character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to print a *new line* symbol (`os.linesep`) if only your line does not end with it in order to prevent this additional blank line.

It can be solved with a check like this:

```
import os


with open('iter.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Print with end='' if your line contains a new line
        # Otherwise, print this new line

        linesep = os.linesep
        line_end = '' if linesep in line else linesep

        print(line, end=line_end)
```